# java serverSocket use same port whereas client uses different

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, port, serversocket

in every Java socket program we have a Serversocket and Client Socket with port numbers

I am confused with communication mechanism we have a Fixed port number  for Server and its obvious for server to take connections one one port number however we have different port from clients , i mean  every time it give me different port number when I print

```
System.out.println("caught a client : "+ client.getInetAddress() +" : "+ client.getPort());
```

I want to know the reason why clients port number is different every time

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TCP socket connection is identified by 4 fields: source address and port, and destination address and port. If you used a fixed port on the client side you wouldn't be able to make another connection to the same server and port.

Usually it does not matter which port the client chooses, as long as it's not in use. Most programs leave it to the operating system to find a free port.

Comment: It is important actually. It's critical to distinguish newly created socket conenction.

Comment: @zgulser clarified that what's unimportant is which port you pick, provided it's free